# NPE on directory.listFiles(), probably

Tags: android, android-file

My App has a Service which monitors a specific directory for new file creation...

I haven't faced this Crash but these are reported on Store by users...
I have also added Runtime Permissions on my App's Splash Activity.

Here is the NotificationService -

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
private NotificationManager mNM;
private Notification notif;

private HelperMethods helperMethods;
private final String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
private final String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/ExampleDir/Directory/";
private static int count = 0;

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    NotificationService getService() {
        return NotificationService.this;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
    helperMethods = new HelperMethods(NotificationService.this);
    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    int isWritingPermissionGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int isReadingPermissionGrannted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if(isReadingPermissionGrannted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && isWritingPermissionGranted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    CheckForNewFiles();
    }

    else{
        showPermNotification();
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}


private void showPermNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(NotificationService.this);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    notification.setContentTitle("Error")
        .setContentText("Storage Permission is Needed!")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setShowWhen(true)
        .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 250 , 250 , 250})
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));

        notif = notification.getNotification();
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNM.notify(0, notif);

}


public void CheckForNewFiles(){
    Date fileDate;
    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/ExampleDir/Directory/";
    File tp = new File(targetPath);
    if(!tp.exists()){
        tp.mkdirs();
    }

    File[] targetDirectory = new File(targetPath).listFiles();
    //GETTING ERROR HERE, ON EMPTY LINE
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("latestFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long lastSavedDateToString = sp.getLong("latestFile", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Date lastDate = new Date(lastSavedDateToString);

    count = targetDirectory.length;
    Log.d("Files Count", "" + count);

    if(targetDirectory != null && count > 0){
    for(File f : targetDirectory){
        fileDate = new Date(f.lastModified());

        if(fileDate.compareTo(lastDate)>0){
            showNotification();
        }//IF END
       }//FOR END
      }//IF END

        new AlarmTask(this).run();

}}
```

Even the Permission is added & a null check is added, it throws a NPE

Comment: Not exactly the line you claim but: `listFiles()` can return null and your `targetDirectory.length` derefs a potential null that can lead to NPE.

Comment: @laalto any solution?

Comment: Have a `!= null` check before `.length`.

Comment: @laalto seems legit :)